# Difference between @with_kw and Base.@kwdef in Julia?

Tags: julia

Inspired by a comment on this question: [What does @with_kw do in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69586136/what-does-with-kw-do-in-julia), what is the difference between `@with_kw` from [Parameters.jl](https://github.com/mauro3/Parameters.jl) and [Base.@kwdef](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f2080d57c8fb796f8f05dc4914e27094a600bcf8/base/util.jl#L428)? Why would I use one versus the other?

Comment: It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/?_ga=2.234024286.1949022841.1631233456-1690002512.1626695629&_gac=1.118873467.1631243013.Cj0KCQjw4eaJBhDMARIsANhrQAAr9FjQp8hjie7s2gkeOGuC4H9izpdqrerj3VpLe7e9l0cnTHr_1bsaAmPYEALw_wcB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The biggest difference that I can see is the support for different macros. In the case of `Base.@kwdef`, while it is accessible through Julia, it is an un-exported internal macro meaning it is not fully supported as part of the public API. You can read more about that here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/33192

Based on that fact alone, it is likely a better practice to make use of the Parameters.jl instead of the one from base as it will be more stable until the macro is publicly supported.

As to the underlying technical differences, it does not appear that there is any significant difference in the way you would use either of these macros.

Comment: there seem to be real differences: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/29316#issuecomment-424091405