# Default value in Struct in julia

Tags: struct, constructor, julia

Here is my code

```
mutable struct Foo
    G::Graph
    S::Union{Tuple{Ring, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}},
            Tuple{Ring, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}}
            }


 # External constructor if S is given 
    # »for S (x,q,z) 
     function Foo(G::Graph, S::Tuple{QQMPolyRing, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}})
        return new(G, S)
    end
   #.  » for S (x,q)
    function Foo(G::Graph, S::Tuple{QQMPolyRing, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}, Vector{QQMPolyRingElem}})
        return new(G, S)
    end  

    # Inner constructor with default values for S (x,q,z)
    function Foo(G::Graph)
    
        S=@polynomial_ring(QQ, x[1:2], q[1:3], z[1:2])

        return new(G, S)
    end
 # Inner constructor with default values for S (x,q)
    function Foo(G::Graph)
        
        S=@polynomial_ring(QQ, x[1:2], q[1:3])


        return new(G, S)
    end

end
```

This code works, but I feel like it could be written in a more concise and efficient way.
I tried the modification down, but  I am getting  `UndefVarError:` V `not defined.`

```
 mutable struct Foo {T, V <:Vector{T} where T <:QQMPolyRingElem}
G::Graph
S::Union{Tuple{Ring, V, V },
Tuple{Ring, V,V,V}
}

  function Foo(G::Graph, S::Tuple{Ring, V, V})
      return new(G, S)
  end

 # Inner constructor with default values for S
   function Foo(G::Graph)
      S=@polynomial_ring(QQ, x[1:2], q[1:3])
      return new{G, S)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The following may be useful: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@kwdef

See also: [Difference between @with_kw and Base.@kwdef in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69605856/difference-between-with-kw-and-base-kwdef-in-julia)

For example:

```
Base.@kwdef mutable struct Foo {T, V <:Vector{T} where T <:QQMPolyRingElem}
    G::Graph
    S::Union{Tuple{Ring, V, V },Tuple{Ring, V,V,V}} = @polynomial_ring(QQ, x[1:2], q[1:3])
}
```